# Проверить ввел ли пользователь строку

Tags: java, scanner

уважаемые форумчане!
Написал простую программу, нужно сделать проверку на введенные данные,а то если вводится строка кидается исключение.
Вот код:

```
 ArrayList<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<>();//инициализируем лист,в который будем добавлять регистры числа введенного с клавиатуры
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input num: ");
    int number = sc.nextInt();//инициализируем число введенное с клавиатуры
    int massageNum = number;//записываем число для вывода в сообщение
    if (number<0){ //делаем число положительным для обхода по циклу
        number *=-1;
    }
    for (;number>0;number /=10){//получаем регистры введенного числа
        numList.add(number%10);
    }
    Collections.sort(numList);//сортируем лись в порядке возрастания,н-р 132 -> 123
    System.out.printf("Entered number %d. The highest figure in it is %d.",massageNum,numList.get(numList.size() - 1));
}
```

Comment: `try ... catch`

Comment: ``if (number<0){ number *=-1; }`` заменяется простым ``number = Math.abs(number)``

Answer (score 0):

Для ввода числа без исключения следует использовать метод `Scanner::hasNextInt` для проверки, есть ли во входном потоке число.  Если было введено нечисловое значение, его следует вычитать при помощи `Scanner::next`:

```java
private static int readInt(Scanner scan, String msg) {
    System.out.print(msg);
    while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка ввода: " + scan.next() + ", повторите ввод числа");
    }
    return scan.nextInt();
}
```

вызов где-то в методе `main`:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int number = readInt(sc, "Input num: ");
// ...
```