# Возвращение в начало выбора в switch после обработки исключения в case без падения программы

Tags: java

Не получается никак осилить возврат в начало выбора case после выкидывания ошибки внутри. [image: сам код]

Comment: Во-первых, [не добавляйте, пожалуйста, код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375).  Во-вторых, объясните, что значит ***возврат в начало выбора case***.  Вы хотите, чтобы у вас выполнялся цикл, пока будет некорректный ввод?

Comment: Я только зарегистрировался на сайте и не знаю всех правил:). Мне нужен возврат в выборку действий либо возврат в ввод значения при неправильном вводе

Comment: Пожалуйста, замените картинку на код. Для этого есть кнопка [edit]. И ещё: если ответ вам помог, примите его как решение (галка напротив ответа). Отвечающему будет приятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно переписать данный код, создав отдельный метод, который будет считывать данные и создавать экземпляр `Point`.  Выйти из этого метода можно только когда данные были введены корректно:

```java
private static Point readPoint(Scanner scanner) {
    Point result = null;
    while (result == null) {
        try {
            System.out.print("Введите координаты точки типа double (x y)");
            result = new Point(scanner.nextDouble(), scanner.nextDouble());
        } catch(Exception e) {
             // обработать неправильный ввод в сканере
            System.out.println("Неправильный ввод! " + scanner.next());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

И затем вызывайте этот метод в требуемом случае `case`:

```java
// ...
switch (something) {
    case 1: points.add(readPoint(scanner)); // в список точек добавятся только корректные данные 
            break;
    // ...
}
```

См. [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1463233/386633) на похожий вопрос: [Проверить ввел ли пользователь строку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1463226/)

Comment: Спасибо большое,Логику я понял. Теперь встает другой вопрос, не вызовет ли это конфликт с изначальным классом Point?

Comment: А какой "конфликт" может возникнуть с изначальным классом `Point`?

Comment: Я уже допер. Нет просто сейчас компьютера под рукой, а ваш пример кода прописывается в самом классе Point, являясь его методом

Comment: Добрый вечер. В консоли начало выдавать бесконечный "неправильный ввод"

Comment: Да, поправил код, первоначальный вариант не тестировался